# why we set id parameter in plotly Dash ? can you explain plotly Dash code like below?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
    html.Div([
        "Input: ",
        dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])


@app.callback(

    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-input', component_property='value')
)

def update_output_div(input_value):

    return f'Output: {input_value}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

here they set id='my-input',id='my-output' but why ?